# JQuery reformat text and change order

Tags: jquery, replace, find

I have data set up like this at the moment.

```
<div>zone 1,2 and 3 Tube ticket single to £2.20</div>
<div>zone 1,2 and 4 Bus ticket single to £3.20</div>
```

etc.. and there is a lot.

How would I use Jquery to reformat it like this..

```
<div>123, Tube ticket single, 2.20</div>
<div>124, Bus ticket single, 3.20</div>
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery you can do :

```
    var pattern = /(([\d]),([\d]) and ([\d]) ([\w].*) (to £)([\d]\.[\d][\d]))/;
    var str = 'zone 1,2 and 3 Tube ticket single to £2.20';
    var matches = str.match(pattern);

    var result = matches[2] + matches[3] + matches[4] + ', ' + matches[5] + ', ' + matches[7];
```

Wich displays: "123, Tube ticket single, 2.20"

With jQuery:

```
var pattern = /(([\d]),([\d]) and ([\d]) ([\w].*) (to £)([\d]\.[\d][\d]))/;
$('div').each(function() {
    var matches = $(this).html().match(pattern);
    $(this).html(matches[2] + matches[3] + matches[4] + ', ' + matches[5] + ', ' + matches[7]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:-

For your quick testing, refer the **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HEJuE/)**

### HTML

```
<div>zone 1,2 and 3 Tube ticket single to £2.20</div>
<div>zone 1,2 and 4 Bus ticket single to £3.20</div>
```

### JS

```
$("div").each(function(){

    $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/zone (\d),(\d) and (\d) (.*) to £([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)/g, '$1$2$3, $4, $5'));

});
```

### OUTPUT

```
<div>123, Tube ticket single, 2.20</div>
<div>124, Bus ticket single, 3.20</div>
```